# Call specific method based on the ArrayList value in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Arraylist(which is retrieved from upstream app) which contains around for example 30 values(The count varies). I want to call specific methods based on the values in the arraylist.
For example:

```
List = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
```

If the List contains `"a"` I want to execute `methodA` , similarly for `"b"` and so on. If the List does not contain `"a"` I do not want to run `methodA`.

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

    Map<String, Consumer> ACTIONS = Map.of(
            "a", v -> System.out.println("A"),
            "b", v -> System.out.println("B"),
            "c", v -> System.out.println("C"),
            "d", v -> System.out.println("D"),
            "e", v -> System.out.println("E")
    );

    list.forEach(e -> ACTIONS.get(e).accept(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Java Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html), which allows you to get dynamic information about classes, methods, fields, and so forth at runtime.

Code implementing your approach above:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackOverflow {
    private static class Target {
        public void methodA() {
            System.err.println("methodA");
        }

        public void methodB() {
            System.err.println("methodB");
        }

        public void methodC() {
            System.err.println("methodC");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Target target = new Target();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a", "c" }));
        for (String item : list) {
            target.getClass().getMethod("method" + item.toUpperCase()).invoke(target, new Object[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ javac StackOverflow.java && java StackOverflow
methodA
methodC
```

Answer (score 0):

The below screenshot is a sample.
Code below

```
  static void main(String[] args){
    def yourList = ["a","b","c"]

    //my way of test data
    String sample = "{\"a\" : \"Do action of A\", \"b\":\"Do action of B\"}"
    yourList.each {String value ->

        Map testData = (Map) new JsonSlurper().parseText(sample)
        if(testData.containsKey(value)){
            println(testData.get(value))
        }else {
            println("not found")

        }

    }
}
```

`